# Any tools to check if a Javascript property exists or not?

Tags: javascript, lint, jshint

Given an example code:

```
var yyy = { abc : 1 },
    xxx = yyy.abcc + 1;
```

It won't throw any error but there is a typo where yyy.abcc should be yyy.abc, so xxx is now equal to "NaN" because of the typo error.

I use jslint, jshint to check for problems in codes but it won't tell you if abcc is a valid property or not.

Is there any tools like jslint, or jshint out there that can check this?

Comment: "if (undefined != yyy.abc)" should do the job no ? Or "if (NaN != ParseInt(yyy.abc))".

Comment: @Ricola3D: That's not a tool though ;)

Comment: Not sure of any tools, but if you use TypeScript, the compiler will surely throw an error. All JavaScript is TypeScript compatible. So you can just copy and paste your code.

Comment: @Arun Thanks! It does able to check for problems for the example in the question, but it means I probably need to convert my codes to TypeScript to enjoy the full capabilities. Because by simply copy and paste my javascript codes to check using Typescript it can't check for dependencies (e.g. If my codes uses jQuery, it will gives error TS2095: Could not find symbol '$'.)

Comment: It's really hard to test this with a tool, since you could always have modified the Object prototype to have a property called `abcc`. There could still be some tools though that give at least a warning but I don't know. I would recommend unit testing to find such errors in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling these types of common typos and bugs is indeed a massive hole in the Javascript ecosystem, which I wished more people cared about. The fact that this question was asked eight years ago, and still hasn't received a good answer is a huge concern.

I've looked at a bunch of Javascript tools, and the only one I found that sort of works for your case is the Typescript compiler `tsc`.

Unfortunately, because of the dynamic nature of Javascript maps, it doesn't technically handle your case in the exact way you wrote it, since maps don't have strict attributes that can be enforced, even by a compiler. However, it does work if you instead use a proper Javascript class, which you really should be doing anyways for the other benefits classes provide.

For example, if I rewrite your code as:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.abc = 1;
    }
}

var yyy = new MyClass();
var xxx = yyy.abcc + 1;
```

and put it in the file `test.js`, then create a Typescript config file `tsconfig.json` file containing (mostly just the default output from `tsc --init`):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "test.js"
  ]
}
```

and then run:

```
tsc --build tsconfig.json
```

it correctly outputs the error:

```
test.js:11:15 - error TS2551: Property 'abcc' does not exist on type 'MyClass'. Did you mean 'abc'?

11 var xxx = yyy.abcc + 1;
                 ~~~~

  test.js:6:9
    6         this.abc = 1;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'abc' is declared here.


Found 1 error.
```

Even better, it suggests a useful solution, which is a rarity among compilers.

To install `tsc` and the type definitions it depends on, you can run:

```
sudo npm install typescript -g
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't complicate things :)
The first answer was a good one, every object in javascript has a prototype which can be check by means of "if (undefined != yyy.abc)" this will tell you if "abc" exists withing the var yyy proving yyy is not undefined itself.

Comment: I assume we don't check yyy.abc on every single occurence? Let say yyy.abc is being used a lot in different areas of the codes, we check if ( undefined != yyy.abc ) on main areas but not on every occurence? If not then there is a lot of checks for each variable..

Comment: well i don't know your code to answer that :), but generally if this is the case, then maybe you are in needing of some factoring. But again only by seeing the code can i answer this :)